# static city map from basemap

Tags: python, python-2.7, maps, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to draw a NY map in static way through Basemap in Python

```
west, south, east, north = -74.26, 40.50, -73.70, 40.92

# fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,14))

m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=south, urcrnrlat=north,
            llcrnrlon=west, urcrnrlon=east, lat_ts=south, resolution='i')

m.etopo(scale=0.5, alpha=0.5)
```

But I get [only this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYs6z.png)

I can draw it through `folium` but it will be not static but with a zoom.

Is it possible to draw static map of NY using Basemap

Answer (score 0):

According to the Basemap [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.etopo), `etopo` uses data from the [NOAA page](https://data.nodc.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/iso?id=gov.noaa.ngdc.mgg.dem:316) (which provides a resolution of 1 arc-minute) to display the relief. With the coordinates you provide in your code, I would expect a maximum resolution of about 33x25 pixels.

Now, according again to the Basemap documentation, etopo accepts the `scale` keyword to downscale the data, with `None` as default, but they don't really state what range of values are accepted. I started playing around with this and, with using `scale=5`, in your (slightly adapted) code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

west, south, east, north = -74.26, 40.50, -73.70, 40.92

m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=south, urcrnrlat=north,
            llcrnrlon=west, urcrnrlon=east, lat_ts=south, resolution='i')

result = m.etopo(scale=5)
print(result.get_size())
plt.show()
```

I get the following image (WARNING: this takes some time):

[image]

The output of the `print` command, (i.e. the pixel size of the image) is

```
(32, 32)
```

which puzzles me, as I didn't expect the resolution to become this high in latitudinal direction. I'm guessing that some interpolation is going on, but to be really sure one would have to go through the code to see what the `scale` keyword actually does.